# how to renew lock for a very long processing message on the fly - Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

is it possible to renew lock for a message under process in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus library, if yes how

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you use, you need to extend the lock. Using the processor provided by the Service Bus SDK you've mentioned, it can be done in the following way:

```
await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

// create the options to use for configuring the processor
var options = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
{
    MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45); // Allow message processing for up-to 45 minutes
    AutoCompleteMessages = false,

    // Disable multi-threading for easy debugging
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1
};

await using ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, options);

processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(body);

    await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
}

Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.ErrorSource);

    Console.WriteLine(args.FullyQualifiedNamespace);
    Console.WriteLine(args.EntityPath);

    Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

processor.StartProcessingAsync();
Console.ReadKey();
```

They key is the [`MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessoroptions.maxautolockrenewalduration?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusprocessoroptions-maxautolockrenewalduration) property that needs to be set to the maximum possible time.

In case you're using [`ServiceBusReceiver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver?view=azure-dotnet#methods), it provides [`RenewMessageLockAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.renewmessagelockasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusreceiver-renewmessagelockasync(azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusreceivedmessage-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method to achieve the goal.

Comment: In addition, when using Azure Functions with `ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions`, there is `RenewMessageLockAsync`, but only since version 5.3.

Comment: Two warnings about that: 1) only available with In-Process SDK at this time and 2) renewing beyond the maximum execution time on consumption tier will fail as function will be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Message lock **renewal** is only **applied** to messages that are **actively processed** by endpoints and **do not apply** to messages that have been **prefetched**.

The message lock renewal time should be longer than the **LockDuration** time.

The Azure Service Bus transport will send a lock renewal request to the broker when the **LockDuration period is about to expire**, keeping the message locked and **invisible** to other consumers.

While the **total time of message processing is less than the auto-renewal time set by Azure Service Bus transport, lock renewal will occur automatically**.

The lock renewal time is set to 5 minutes by default. The **DeliveryCount** of the processed message will not rise if the auto-lock is renewed.

The message lock is renewed for the message that is presently being handled. When prefetched messages are completed by the transport, they will lose their lock if they are not handled within the **LockDuration** time. This will be signaled by a **LockLostException** in the log. Prefetching can be deactivated to avoid the lock renewal exception by setting **PrefetchCount** to zero.

#### Configuring message to lock renewal

```cs
var ServiceBusTransport= endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>(); 
var ServiceBusReceivers = ServiceBusTransport.MessageReceivers(); 
ServiceBusReceivers .AutoRenewTimeout(maximumProcessingTime);
```

Refer [here](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/legacy/message-lock-renewal#:%7E:text=Lock%20renewal%20will%20automatically%20take,DeliveryCount%20of%20the%20processed%20message.) for more information.

Comment: You're providing NServiceBus code snippet and referring to NServiceBus API. The OP didn't mention anything about NServiceBus 